# (ClientSide) set/update JSlink to CSR files for (all) WebParts, Views, Fields

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, jslink, client-side-rendering

Working on [iCSR.github.io](http://iCSR.github.io) to make CSR development a bit easier.

I now want to make it as easy as possible to set the JSlink connections on WebParts, Views or Fields.

I have code snippets to do it all, not one UI for all

**Just wondering if there already is a tool/JSlink manager that does all this JSlink-ing (on a current page) or even shows all existing links in one overview**

- Apply a JSlink to the current WebPart
- Apply a JSlink to Views (and not overwriting existing links to clienttemplates/hierarchytaskslist)
- Apply a JSlink to a Field

Thinking ahead, would be cool to have one ASPX page to control everything JSlink in a Site Collection

Can't find info on it; Can ShareGate manage JSlink settings?

Comment: I'm assuming you know about the Chrome extension CISAR, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: Oh yes, have been a Cisar user for some time (*and call it the best thing since sliced bread*). But Cisar only adds its own CSR file to the JSlink (and only on the WebPart). It is not a JSlink manager for all places a JSlink can be set.

Comment: Ah, k. I haven't used it enough to know if it surfaced all the applied JSLinks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote my own JSLink Manager (runs as a Browser Bookmarklet)

To:

- add/delete JSlinks on WebParts/Views in order
- Immediate save/apply on any change

[image]

Have to refactor it a bit to work it into the [iCSR](http://iCSR.github.io) library

Update #1

http://icsr.github.io/JSLinkManager.html
 is my current version of the JSLinkManager as Bookmarklet...